# Get informations about Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-functions, monitoring, kql, azure-log-analytics

I want to monitor a platform in Azure.
I need to get two main KPIs in my storage part: first, I need to get the number of requests in my Azure SQL Database, and second, I need to get the average database response time.

In order to get information about my Azure SQL Database, I used to check the AzureMetrics table in LogAnalytics. I got a few KPIs with this table, but I can’t find information about the two KPIs below.
Is there a way to get these two metrics? Using loganalytics, or maybe an API requestin
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct metric in Metrics section of Azure SQL in portal to get number of requests in Azure SQL Database or Average response time in Azure SQL Database. But you can connect your Azure SQL Database to SSMS and get the requests and response time logs.

Query [**Reference**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```sql
Select * From sys.dm_exec_requests
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

You can run the query below to get more information on execution counts on your Azure SQL DB and their  response time:-

Query [**Reference**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```sql
Select * From sys.dm_exec_query_stats
```

**Output:-**

[image]

You can visit your SSMS connected to Azure SQL > Query store and get the Overall Resource consumption which will give you the same details refer below:-

[image]

[image]

You can find these details in Azure SQL Database on Portal like below:-

[image]

I have sent the logs from my Azure SQL DB Diagnostic settings to Azure Log analytics workspace and I get the same Query Store parameters with also CPU metrics of Azure SQL like below:-
Reference [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/metrics-diagnostic-telemetry-logging-streaming-export-configure?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-portal)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]